# Kafka consumer manual commit offset

Tags: java, spring, apache-kafka, spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl

I'm implementing and dsl spring integration flow which takes messages from Kafka

Code snippet:

```
return IntegrationFlows.from(
                Kafka.messageDrivenChannelAdapter(new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory(kafkaTelemetryDataConsumerConfiguration.getConsumerProperties()),
                        kafkaPropertiesConfiguration.getTelemetryDataTopic()))
                })
                .handle(bla.someImportantOperation())
                //TODO:do manual commit here
                //.handle(consumer.commitSync())

                .get();
```

I would like to know how can I manually commitSync but only after `.handle(bla.someImportantOperation())` has successfuly finished.

I don't know how to get the consumer reference since I'm using DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory, would appreciate any help.

These are my consumerProperties I use to create consumer:

```
consumerProperties.setProperty(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, kafkaPropertiesConfiguration.getBootstrapServers());
consumerProperties.setProperty(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class.getName());
consumerProperties.setProperty(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, ByteArrayDeserializer.class.getName());

consumerProperties.setProperty(ConsumerConfig.CLIENT_ID_CONFIG, kafkaPropertiesConfiguration.getClientIdConfig());
consumerProperties.setProperty(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, kafkaPropertiesConfiguration.getGroupIdConfig());

consumerProperties.setProperty(ConsumerConfig.ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT_CONFIG, "false");
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `Kafka.messageDrivenChannelAdapter()` provides for you a configurer hook:

```
.configureListenerContainer(c ->
                                c.ackMode(ContainerProperties.AckMode.MANUAL))
```

Pay attention to the option I provide.

Read its Javadocs and then `AcknowledgingMessageListener`.
There is a mentioning of the `Acknowledgment`. this one is present in the message headers via `KafkaHeaders.ACKNOWLEDGMENT`.

so, what you need in your `//.handle(consumer.commitSync())` is just something like this:

```
.handle(m -> headers.get(KafkaHeaders.ACKNOWLEDGMENT, Acknowledgment.class).acknowledge())
```

See more info in Spring for Apache Kafka Docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/2.2.0.RELEASE/reference/html/_reference.html#committing-offsets